# ¿Cómo añadir color con transparencia sobre el background?

Tags: css, css3

Resulta que en una página html y css que estoy creando, de background tengo una fotografía, pero quiero añadir sobre esa fotografía un color sólido con transparencia, digamos un 50% de opacidad, he probado colocando antes de la sección que contiene al background un div con una clase y a esta colocarle un fondo de color con 50% de opacidad, pero termina arruinando el background con fotografía y no se termina viendo ninguno de los dos, por lo que terminé quitando ese div y colocando la clase dentro de la misma sección, pero tampoco funciona. ¿Cómo podría lograr hacer lo que quiero?

Esto es lo que había hecho:

HTML

```
<section id="der" class="transparencia">    
        <h4 class="cabeceras">Hola, soy</h4>
        <h1 class="cabeceras">Pedro Fumero</h1>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.transparencia {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
section#der {
    background: url("../img/home.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100%;
    float: center;
}
```

Comment: Hola @PedroFumero, puedes probar a añadir un <div> dentro de la etiqueta <section> que encierre a los dos encabezados, y a ese div añadele la clase transparencia, y quitále esa clase a la etiqueta <section>. Prueba y comentas. Un saludo

Comment: usando color rgba, o la opción opacity en el css.

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente tienes que crear una caja/capa, (en el ejemplo un `div`) por separado para crear una capa encima de la imagen... además `float: center;` no existe:

```css
.transparencia {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

section#der {
    width: 350px;
    height: 150px;
    background: url("http://placehold.it/350x150");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: cover;
    /* float: center; no existe */
}
```

```html
<section id="der">
   <div class="transparencia">
        <h4 class="cabeceras">Hola, soy</h4>
        <h1 class="cabeceras">Pedro Fumero</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: no serviria poner mas brillo a la imagen?, no quiero decir que tu respuesta es mala, por el contrario es perfecta, pero como alternativa?

Comment: @x-rw - creo que haz entendido mal la pregunta... lo que quiere el OP es una capa de color transparente encima de la otra imagen... (para tu info: no te he votado negativo)

Answer (score 2):

También podrías hacerlo usando:

- [`:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/::before): Crea un `pseudo-elemento` que sera le primer hijo del elemento seleccionado.

Así por ejemplo:

```css
.transparencia {
  position: relative;
}
.transparencia > * {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.transparencia:before {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  content: '';
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
section#der {
    background: url("http://placehold.it/650x150");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="der" class="transparencia">    
  <h4 class="cabeceras">Hola, soy</h4>
  <h1 class="cabeceras">Pedro Fumero</h1>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que lo que quieres es aplicar una capa de color por encima de la imagen, con cierta transparencia para no ocultar esa imagen.

Prueba con esto:

HTML:

```
<section id="der">    
    <div class="transparencia">
        <h4 class="cabeceras">Hola, soy</h4>
        <h1 class="cabeceras">Pedro Fumero</h1>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.transparencia {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
section#der {
    background: url('https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/588111282198487040/MP4hXrUQ.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
}
```

Un saludo

Comment: Excelente amigos, gracias por la ayuda, esto es justamente lo que estaba buscando. Y gracias también por aclararme que float: center no existía :)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es crear una "capa", hacerla absoluta y que ocupe las dimensiones del padre. Esto puedes hacerlo mediante un `div` o mediante `:before` y `:after`. Además, es muy **importante** que, si tienes algo **pulsable** como links, botones, selects, inputs o demás, hacerlo indiferente a eventos mediante `pointer-events: none`. Te pongo un ejemplo de esto, si le quitas `pointer-events: none` verás que ningún elemento es clickeable.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web');

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/nvFrytk.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu ul {
  line-height: 50px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.menu ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Titillium web';
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu:after {
  background-color: rgba(35, 88, 188, .1);
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```